# Weakly null sequence $(x_n)$ implies $|x^*(x_n)|<\epsilon?$

Tags: functional-analysis

Is it always true that a weakly null sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ implies the inequality 
$$|x^*(x_n)|<\epsilon?$$

Recall that a weakly null sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence converges to $0$ weakly. So for all linear functionals $x^* \in X^*$, we have
$$|x^*(x_n) - x^*(0)|<\epsilon$$

My guess is that $x^*(0)=0$ but it seems not always the case to me. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Any linear map takes 0 to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Prahlad Vaidyanathan, you always have $x^*(0) = 0$. Indeed, by linearity you have
$x^*(0) = x^*(0+0) = x^*(0) + x^*(0)$ or $x^*(0) = x^*(0\cdot 0) = 0 \cdot x^*(0) = 0$.